# Using reference PCB trace antennas without tuning them

Tags: pcb-antenna

I would like to integrate the following reference design of an inverted F antenna into my design http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swru120b/swru120b.pdf
but I am concerned with its performance with the rest of my system. I don't have access to a network analyzer to look at the performance of the antenna and tune it. Does anyone have any experience with using reference designs of trace antennas and running into issues with performance? If I do run into performance issues, is it possible to resolve them without using a network analyzer (i.e. is tuning without a network analyzer possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This antenna is fairly broad band and omni-directional, so I would expect it to be relatively insensitive to normal manufacturing variation.  Also, as it describes, it doesn't use a bottom side ground plane, which makes it less sensitive to the thickness and dielectric constant of the PCB.

There are ways to tune without a network analyzer, but it really depends on what tools you do have.  This antenna is not really designed for tunability   anyway, so I don't know what you would do even if you had a network analyzer, other than maybe rescale the drawing slightly to shift the peak frequency.  I don't really think you are going to have a problem just making this as-is.

Comment: Ya shifting the peak frequency is what I had in mind. So just in case there are issues; I have an oscilloscope, a DMM, a 3 output dc power supply and a 20 MHz arbitrary waveform generator anything I can do with that (I know it might be asking for a lot)?